# How do I set deault browser to NOT rekonq?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, default-browser, rekonq

I don't like rekonq, and I don't want rekonq, so I uninstalled it. However, now whenever I click on a link in another program (e.g. a pdf) it complains that it can't find rekonq. I want to keep using KDE, but without rekonq - is that possible? How do I change it to NOT try to open rekonq?

So far, the only solution I can think of is to make a symlink pointing from "rekonq" to the browser I actually want to use. Is this the only option? Surely there must be a setting somewhere that I can change, to make rekonq not the default browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To solve this, open KDE System Settings or run systemsettings from
  shell.
- Now select Default Applications under Workspace Appreance and
  Behaviour group.
- In the left pane, select Web Browser, and in the Default Component
  groupbox, change command of the browser to firefox from rekonq.

Another way to do it is remove mime-type from rekonq desktop launcher file if it is **still there in the system**. Just open the following file with nano/kate or whatever you like and add a `#` in front of line starting with MimeType.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/kde4/rekonq.desktop
```

Put a `#` as follows

```
Icon=rekonq
Type=Application
Exec=rekonq %u
X-DocPath=rekonq/index.html
Categories=Qt;KDE;Network;WebBrowser;
Terminal=false
#MimeType=text/html;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;
X-DBUS-StartupType=Unique
X-DBUS-ServiceName=org.kde.rekonq
InitialPreference=10
```